# Upgrading magento 2.1.10

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have a Magento 2.1.10 installation that I want to upgrade purely for security updates.

With Magento 1 I used to be able to just apply patches to achieve this. But from what I understand with Magento 2 you have to upgrade the installation to get security updates? So to get the updates for 2.1.10 I would update to the latest in the 2.1.x branch? Are these update generally quite painless or am I going to experience issues? Presumably as I am wanting to keep in the 2.1 branch it should be more straightforward than if I were to update to 2.2.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you don't upgrade the version of the magento instance i.e 2.1.x to 2.2.x , its painless as per my experience,however you have to take backup of database and files before running the upgrade. For more details you may visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html